# Rsync how to include directories but not files?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I have a directory structure and files like this

```
data/
data/a.txt
data/folder/
data/folder/b.txt
data/folder/folder/
data/folder/folder/c.txt
...
```

`a.txt`, `b.txt`, and `c.txt` are large files that are computer-generated and renewed frequently. They should NOT be backuped -- but I want to backup the directory structure :

```
data/
data/folder/
data/folder/folder/
```

How can I do this with rsync and --exclude-from, without specifying every folder, but something like `rsync -a data/* --exclude-from=exclude.rsync "" --onlyfoldersandnotfiles""`?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 64):

```
rsync -a --include='*/' --exclude='*' source/ destination/
```

Basically, first include all directories, then exclude all files.

Comment: Isn't this the same as [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9242883)?

Comment: @roaima Yes I precisely posted Steve's comment as an answer, because I agree with him that it's a lot more readable that way than with those weird `-f"±` arguments.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks thank you for making this a separate answer

Answer (score 46):

```
$ rsync -a -f"+ */" -f"- *" source/ destination/
```

"The two -f arguments mean, respectively, "copy all directories" and then "do not copy anything else"."

Further details: http://psung.blogspot.com/2008/05/copying-directory-trees-with-rsync.html

Comment: A really brilliant solution. Way simpler than combining `--include` and `--exclude` for basic use.

Comment: IMHO this is much more readable: `rsync -a --include='*/' --exclude='*' source/ destination/`

Comment: @SteveBennett include and exclude are just synonyms for filters + and -. How could they be more reliable?

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko "readable" not "reliable".

Answer (score 5):

```
rsync -a -f"-! */" source/ destination/
```

Filter rule means "Exclude anything that's not a directory."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sync everything except one folder but you still want to keep the directory structure of that excluded folder, you should do the following:

```
$ rsync -a -f"+ /var/log/**/*/" -f"- /var/log/**/*" source/ destination/
```

See the [exclude-list](https://github.com/ceremcem/smith-sync/blob/a1471fd6e568ac6e33b6b320308f822c33d2fe82/exclude-list.txt#L18-L19) and [the rsync command](https://github.com/ceremcem/smith-sync/blob/a1471fd6e568ac6e33b6b320308f822c33d2fe82/rsync.sh#L137-L138) as an example.

Comment: this doesn't specifically answer the OP question so maybe why it was downvoted, but it 
 is way useful for saving the directory structure of a particular directory without the contents which is important for saving then restoring a filesystem folder where you don't want to save the logs for example but do need to save the folder structure so that when you restore you don't get errors associated with missing folders the OS needs to write to.  So my upvote at least brings it back to 0