# copy a directory structure with file names without content

Tags: linux, copy, structure, rsync

I have a huge directory structure of movie files. For analysis of that structure I want to copy the entire directory structure, i.e. folders and files however I don't want to copy all the movie files while I want to keep there file names. Ideally I get zero-byte files with the original movie file name.

I tried to  and then rsync to my remote machine which didn't fetch the link files.

Any ideas how to do that w/o writing scripts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use find:

```
find src/ -type d -exec mkdir -p dest/{} \; \
       -o -type f -exec touch dest/{} \;
```

Find directory (`-d`) under (`src/`) and create (`mkdir -p`) them under `dest/` or (`-o`) find files (`-f`) and `touch` them under `dest/`.

This will result in:

```
dest/src/<file-structre>
```

You can user `mv` creatively to resolve this issue.

---

Other (partial) solution can be achieved with rsync:

```
rsync -a --filter="-! */" sorce_dir/ target_dir/
```

The trick here is the `--filter=RULE` option that excludes (`-`) everything that is not (`!`) a directory (`*/`)

Answer (score 16):

On ubuntu you can try:

```
cp -r --attributes-only <source_dir> <target_dir>
```

It doesn't copy file data.
From manpage of `cp`

```
--attributes-only
          don't copy the file data, just the attributes
```

Note: I'm not sure this option available for other distributions, if anybody can confirm please update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rohan, unfortunately my Debian on Netgear's ReadyNAS won't know this option :(

Comment: works fine under Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Answer (score 0):

I needed an alternative to this to sync only the file structure:

```
rsync --recursive --times --delete --omit-dir-times --itemize-changes "$src_path/" "$dst_path"
```

This is how I realized it:

```
# sync source to destination
while IFS= read -r -d '' src_file; do
  dst_file="$dst_path${src_file/$src_path/}"
  # new files
  if [[ ! -e "$dst_file" ]]; then
    if [[ -d "$src_file" ]]; then
      mkdir -p "$dst_file"
    elif [[ -f $src_file ]]; then
      touch -r "$src_file" "$dst_file"
    else
      echo "Error: $src_file is not a dir or file"
    fi
    echo -n "+ "
    ls -ld "$src_file"
  # modification time changed (files only)
  elif [[ -f $dst_file ]] && [[ $(date -r "$src_file") != $(date -r "$dst_file") ]]; then
    touch -r "$src_file" "$dst_file"
    echo -n "+ "
    ls -ld "$src_file"
  fi
done < <(find "$src_path" -print0)

# delete files in destination if they disappeared in source
while IFS= read -r -d '' dst_file; do
  src_file="$src_path${dst_file/$dst_path/}"
  # file disappeard on source
  if [[ ! -e "$src_file" ]]; then
    delinfo=$(ls -ld "$dst_file")
    if [[ -d "$dst_file" ]] && rmdir "$dst_file" 2>/dev/null; then
      echo -n "- $delinfo"
    elif [[ -f $dst_file ]] && rm "$dst_file"; then
      echo -n "- $delinfo"
    fi
  fi
done < <(find "$dst_path" -print0)
```

As you can see I use `echo` and `ls` to display changes.

Answer (score -3):

ls > listOfMovie.txt; You will have the list of your films in a .txt file
.For multiple directories see the man page.