# Replicate a directory file structure with empty files

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, filesystems, directory-structure

I have a directory with this structure (real use case: thousands of files, 400GB directory!):

```
mydir/
|---- blabla.mp4         3.2 GB
|---- foo/
       |----- blup/
       |----- test.wav   245 MB
       |----- test.txt   12 KB
|---- xyz/
       |----- test2.txt  10 KB
|---- zzz.wav            100 MB
```

**How to replicate the tree structure + filename structure and get this, with Windows?**

```
mydir_structure/
|---- blabla.mp4         0.0 KB
|---- foo/
       |----- blup/
       |----- test.wav   0.0 KB
       |----- test.txt   0.0 KB
|---- xyz/
       |----- test2.txt  0.0 KB
|---- zzz.wav            0.0 KB
```

Comment: For unix-based system: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11952522/6306190

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From windows vista, `robocopy` is included in the OS (for previous versions there is a download from Microsoft)

```
robocopy \mydir \mydir_structure /create /e
```

`/e` indicates a recursive copy including empty folders.

`/create` creates the empty files in the target hierarchy.