# Copy a directory structure and only touch the copied files

Tags: linux, file, directory, copy, snakemake

I want to mimic copying a directory structure recursively (as in `cp -r` or `rsync -a`), but only touch the copied files, i.e. make all the copied files empty.

The specific use case is for a [Snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) pipeline; Snakemake looks for existing files in order to decide whether to re-run a pipeline step, and I want to make it believe the steps have already been run while avoiding fully downloading all the files.

Comment: Would making a dummy version of your pipeline, where rules just touch their outputs, do the job?

Comment: The only way I can see doing that is by adding `touch()` to the `output:` part of each rule? That would be too impractical.

Comment: Not sure this really helps in your case, but I see in `snakemake --help` that there is a `--touch` option that can be combined with `--forceall`.

Comment: I did think of that but `--touch` option 'Fails if a file does not yet exist'

Comment: I think similar/same question with some more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946465/copy-a-directory-structure-with-file-names-without-content/11952522#11952522

Comment: e.g. `cp -r --attributes-only <source_dir> <target_dir>` (on Debian / Ubuntu). cred @Rohan

Answer (score 2):

This is a little kludgy, but you could pipe the output of `find` or `rsync -nv` into a little bash loop with `mkdir -p` and `touch`:

```sh
find /some/dir -type f | while read FILE; do
  mkdir -p $(dirname $FILE)
  touch $FILE
done
```