# Copy directory structure ignoring some files

Tags: linux, directory, structure

> I have a directory structure

```
./
└── file1
   ├── config.xml
   ├── config.yml
   └── file2
       ├── config.xml
       ├── config.yml
       └── file3
           ├── config.xml
           └── config.yml
```

> What i want is to copy same directory structure and everything but
>   ignoring config.yml files in the new location Any Linux Command or
>   script Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you just want to replicate the folder structure,

> You could do something like:
>
> `find . -type d >dirs.txt`
>
> to create the list of directories, then
>
> `xargs mkdir -p <dirs.txt`
>
> to create the directories on the destination.

Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073992/6916391

Comment: I want to replicate directory structure along with files in those directories ignoring few of them

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps by copying the whole structure and then removing the config.yml files, this is:

```
cp -R old_structure_parent_dir new_structure_parent_dir
find new_structure_parent_dir -name config.yml -exec rm -rf {} \;
```