How can I copy/clone only the folder structure between images using Docker?
For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have the following structure in the source image:
files/
    folder1/
        file1
        file2
    folder2/
        file1
        file2

I want to have a result where only the directory structure is copied to my other image during build. The result should therefore look like this:
files/
    folder1/
    folder2/

How can this be achieved?
Background: You might ask why I want to do this. Well, in reality the directory structure is much more complex and I need to maintain consistency between both source and destination image. And as there are significant amounts of data in the source image I cannot simply copy over everything and then remove the files (as this would take a lot of time).

You can probably use find in the source image to output the directory structure then use that to create the directories in the new image. This answer should help, just run the commands in the respective containers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073992/735398

How is docker relevant at all here? Is the answer the same when you have a directory structure in one direcory, and want to copy to another directory?


How can this be achieved?

Dynamic programming:

get the list of directories
create them

So something along:
(cd dir1 && find . -depth -type d) | (cd dir2 && xargs mkdir -p)

The specifics, programming language, the representation of "the list of directories", quoting and anything may change - the algorithm stays.
You can do it better by zero separated list:
(cd dir1 && find . -depth -type d -print0) | (cd dir2 && xargs -0 mkdir -p)

And you can prepend docker to it:
docker exec image1 sh -c 'cd dir1 && find . -depth -type d -print0' | docker exec -i image2 sh -c 'cd dir2 && xargs -0 mkdir -p'

Or you could save the list to a file and then use it in dockerfile:
# on host
$ docker run -ti --rm image1 sh -c 'cd dir1 && find . -depth -type d -print0' > dirlist.bin

# in Dockerfile
COPY dirlist.bin ./
RUN cd dir2 && xargs -0 mkdir -p <dirlist.bin


Sorry, I should have been more precise. Everything should take place in the Docker file.

There's no need to generate a file listing all of the folders. With docker you can generate your target directory structure in a temporary stage, and copy those directories in a multi-stage build:
# orig is the upstream original image
FROM alpine AS orig
RUN mkdir -p /src/files/folder1 /src/files/folder2 \
 && touch /src/files/folder1/file1 /src/files/folder1/file2 \
 && touch /src/files/folder2/file1 /src/files/folder2/file2

# create a staging image based on your original image with the created directory structure
FROM orig AS staging
RUN mkdir -p /output \
 && (cd /src && find . -depth -type d) | (cd /output && xargs mkdir -p)

# copy that directory structure to your image
FROM alpine AS result
COPY --from=staging /output /src

Since staging is based on orig, no files are copied and you can do the work of creating the structure in staging target, and then copy that across. The resulting image only contains the directory structure with no temporary files that clutter the filesystem layers.

Actually Pádraig Galvin and KamilCuk pointed to what I wanted to achieve. This how I did it in the end:
# Some dummy image that would hold data in real life
FROM alpine:latest AS some_image
RUN mkdir -p /my/dir/structure/is/deep

# Export the folder structure
FROM some_image AS source
RUN find /my -type d > dir_export.txt

# Import to destination image
FROM alpine:latest AS destination
COPY --from=source ./dir_export.txt /.
RUN xargs mkdir -p < /dir_export.txt
RUN rm /dir_export.txt

It gives the same structure in "some_image" and "destination":
/ # tree my
my
└── dir
    └── structure
        └── is
            └── deep

