# Copy directory tree without files and hidden directories

Tags: directory, rsync, hidden-files

This is a follow up to [Copy folder structure (without files) from one location to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073969/copy-folder-structure-without-files-from-one-location-to-another) and [Rsync how to include directories but not files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546001/rsync-how-to-include-directories-but-not-files), though not a duplicate.

In essence, I want to do the same, i.e.
**copy a directory tree from `src` to `dst` without copying any files** (recursively), except that I also want to **skip all hidden folders** (recursively).

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45960021/1458343) by adding `--exclude '.*/'` did not work as expected:

```bash
rsync -av --include '*/' --exclude '.*/' --exclude '*' src/ dst/
```

as it copies also hidden (dot) directories, `.hidden` in the following example:

```
building file list ... done
./
.hidden/
a/
a/.hidden/
```

I would appreciate an explanation why the attempt does not work as well as a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the rsync man-page:

> The order of the rules is important because the first rule that matches is the one that takes effect.

So, move the include after the first exclude::

```
rsync -av  --exclude '.*/' --include '*/' --exclude '*' src/ dst/
```